# Can Laravel Dusk test results be logged?

Tags: laravel, logging, automated-tests, laravel-dusk

Dusk is providing individual logs for tests that returned failures / warnings in the console, but what I'm really after is one big log file or report that lists the pass/fail status of each test in my Dusk script.

Can anyone suggest a way to go about this? I can't find an answer anywhere but it seems like it should be a relatively common thing to need so I'm sure I've overlooked something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use PHPUnit's logging:

```
php artisan dusk --log-junit junit.log
php artisan dusk --log-teamcity teamcity.log
```

Comment: The junit output is exactly what I needed - thanks very much!

Comment: What if you are doing `->dump()` in the test in that case how do you make sure the dump is logged to a file as well? At the moment using  --log-junit and --log-teamcity it is not.

Comment: You'll have to handle that yourself: `file_put_contents('source.html', $browser->driver->getPageSource());`

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir for some reason junit log file is empty but teamcity is correct, any idea why? I am using Dusk 5.1

Comment: @PetarVasilev Both options work for me. Can you try it on a fresh installation?

Comment: @PetarVasilev Can you test the `ExampleTest.php` file in your current application? `php artisan dusk tests/Browser/ExampleTest.php --log-junit junit.log`

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir that worked, so it's something in my tests that is breaking it?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir some of my tests actually log with the following error: SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: Chrome version must be between 70 and 73

Comment: I tried your package staudenmeir/dusk-updater and did 'php artisan dusk:update 73' but still get the same error. Besides that the not logging still persists...

Comment: @PetarVasilev Did rebooting fix the logging?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir no it didn't unfortunately : (. I've asked this in a separate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56725542/laravel-dusk-junit-doesnt-log-to-file

Comment: Can we configure so that the log filenames match the test names?