# Redirecting command line output doesn't work when running "php artisan dusk"

Tags: bash, laravel, ubuntu, laravel-dusk

I am using Laravel to build a website and I am running some tests using Dusk and I got some errors in the tests but I can't seem them all as my terminal can't scroll through the output. I tried to pipe the result to `less` but when I try to scroll in `less` it gives me an empty page. I, also, tried feeding the output to a file using the following:

```
php artisan dusk tests/Browser/PeopleTest.php &> ~/Downloads/dusk.txt
```

I also tried using `2>` instead of `&>` but the result is the same, the file `dusk.txt` gets created but nothing is saved in it and I can still see the output in the terminal.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: The output is going to standard error instead of standard output. Redirect file descriptor 2 (`2>`)

Comment: @Poshi I tried that too same result as &>

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/50743287/4848587 help you?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir partially, I've commented on your answer there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `--without-tty` option:

```
php artisan dusk --without-tty tests/Browser/PeopleTest.php &> ~/Downloads/dusk.txt
```